# Trying to calculate the maximum of a function but I do not get the right answer?

Tags: python, function, max, sympy, derivative

I am trying to calculate the maximum point of a function. My code is:

```
def S(t):
    return (10*sympy.E**(t/12)*((sympy.sin((sympy.pi*t)/24))**2))
sympy.plotting.plot(S(t), (t,0,24))
deriv = sympy.diff(S(t), t)
test = sympy.Eq(deriv, 0) 
deriv1 = sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(S(t), x), 0, sympy.Interval(10,20))
sympy.solveset(deriv1)
```

Afer, plotting it shows that the maximum should be around t=14. I tried several other methods:

```
expn = sympy.solveset(sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(S(t)), 0))
gfg  = expn.evalf()
sympy.pprint(gfg)
```

I also tried the following:

```
sympy.solveset(test)
```

I still do not get t=14. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `solveset` might returns a better formal solution, it is often difficult to manipulate it in order to get numerical values. This is one of those cases in which it is much better to use `solve` instead, and loop over its solutions to find the one you are looking for:

```py
solutions = sympy.solve(sympy.Eq(S(t).diff(t), 0), t)
print(solutions)
# out: [0, 24, 48*atan((1 - sqrt(1 + pi**2))/pi)/pi, 48*atan((1 + sqrt(1 + pi**2))/pi)/pi]
```

Note that the third and fourth solutions have not been evaluated:

```py
[s.n() for s in solutions]
# out: [0, 24.0000000000000, -9.64576171314495, 14.3542382868550]
```

There you go, the last one is the solution you are looking for.